# Fetching the values from db using doctrine in array format.

Tags: arrays, zend-framework

In my controller, i fetched the values from db using doctrine in array format. The array look like this

```
Array(

[0] => Admin_Model_prod Object
    (
        [_id:protected] => 1         
        [_pname:protected] => mobile
        [_categoryname:protected] => device
        [_price:protected] => 10000
        [_status:protected] => sold

    )

[1] => Admin_Model_prod Object
    (
        [_id:protected] => 2         
        [_pname:protected] => tv
        [_categoryname:protected] => device
        [_price:protected] => 50000
        [_status:protected] => sold

    )
```

)

now i want to display the values with id=1..

any suggestion pls

Answer (score 1):

```
$userId = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('o.authorId')
        ->from("Offer o")
        ->where("o.id =$offerId")
        ->fetchArray();
```

Use your Query like this. you will get an array instead of object

Comment: Consider using parameters to avoid sql injection.
->where("o.id = :id")
->setParameter("id", $offerId)
...